# не работает прокрутка наверх страницы

Tags: javascript, html, css, css3, html5

Всем привет, такая проблема: не работает скролл наверх страницы. Если убрать картинку из ссылки то все хорошо. При клике в event.target выводится не ссылка, а img. Как исправить?

HTML

```
      <section id="first">
        <nav>
          <ul>
            <li><a class="smooth-scroll" href="#first">First</a></li>
            <li><a class="smooth-scroll" href="#second">Second</a></li>
            <li><a class="smooth-scroll" href="#third">Third</a></li>
            <li><a class="smooth-scroll" href="#fourth">Fourth</a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </section>
      <section id="second"></section>
      <section id="third"></section>
      <section id="fourth"></section>

      <a class="pageup smooth-scroll" href="#first">
        <img src="up.svg"/>
      </a>
    </main>
```

CSS

```
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 40px;
  right: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  z-index: 10;
}
.pageup img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

JavaScript

```
    const links = document.querySelectorAll('.smooth-scroll');

    for (let i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
        links[i].addEventListener('click', function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();

            const blockID = event.target.getAttribute("href").substr(1);


            document.getElementById(blockID).scrollIntoView({
                behavior: 'smooth',
                block: 'start'
            })
        })
    }
});
```

Comment: измените `target` -> `currentTarget`

Comment: спасибо вам огромное

Answer (score 0):

При клике на картинку target - картинка.
А тебе нужна не она а  элемент у которого есть атрибут href
по этому один из вариантов использовать currentTarget
А еще у тебя в примере лишние скобки в конце "});" +  substr устарел. лучше заменить. наgример на slice

```js
<script>
  const links = document.querySelectorAll('.smooth-scroll');

  for (let i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {

    links[i].addEventListener('click', function (event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      const blockID = event.currentTarget.getAttribute("href").substr(1);

      document.getElementById(blockID).scrollIntoView({behavior: 'smooth', block: 'start'})
    })
  }

</script>
```

Comment: А ещё это можно реализовать без js с помощью свойства scroll-behavior